# LINQ query to modify a list

Tags: c#, linq, list

This seems to be a tough nut to crack.  I'm hoping that it's pretty easy for you gurus.  I was wondering if this is possible using LINQ.

Here's my list:

```
ABC,1,RON,26,73
CDE,13,JON,21,18
ERROR,ERROR LINE,ERROR LINE,DEF
DEF,NOT AVAILABLE,"",JANE,32,13
GHI,23,DAWN,14,25
```

I need to accomplish 2 things with this list:

1. Move the line with the ERROR and the next line to the bottom of the list
2. The next line after the ERROR (the ones that started with "DEF") has to modified so that the fields all line up as the ones that are correct.  However, I should still remain after the ERROR line.

The final list should look like this:

```
ABC,1,RON,26,73
CDE,13,JON,21,18
GHI,23,DAWN,14,25
ERROR,ERROR LINE,ERROR LINE,DEF
DEF,NOT AVAILABLE,JANE,32,13
```

Right now, my complete, detailed LINQ query looks like this:

```
var myList = (File.ReadLines(myFile.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250)))
    .ToList()
    .OrderBy(l => l[0].ToString())
    .Select(l => new specialclass {
        Comp = l[0].ToString(),
        Place = Convert.ToInt32(l[1].ToString()),
        Name = l[2].ToString(),
        Limit = Convert.ToInt32(l[3].ToString()),
        Limit2 = Convert.ToInt32(l[4].ToString())
    });
```

Comment: How is that data really arranged? Show some code. It doesn't much look like a list to me.

Comment: You cannot modify something while you are enumerating it via linq, so the question appears invalid.   Also, its hard to understand what "my list" is.  Is each line an object in a List<T>?  Or are you talking about running an update query via Linq to Sql?

Comment: I'm reading a legacy text file that has double spaces as a delimiter.  I used commas for simplicity.  Right now, my complete, detailed LINQ query looks like this:  var myList = (File.ReadLines(myFile.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))).ToList()
 .OrderBy(l => l[0].ToString())
 .Select(l => new specialclass
 {
  Comp = l[0].ToString(),
  Place = Convert.ToInt32(l[1].ToString()),
  Name = l[2].ToString(),
  Limit = Convert.ToInt32(l[3].ToString()),
  Limit2 = Convert.ToInt32(l[4].ToString())
 });

Comment: @Will:  is it possible using LINQ to capture all the ERROR lines, the immediately following lines and put it into another list?  Then append that list to my initial list.  Is that possible?

Comment: @inquisitive_one: You could do two selects, Union them and then .ToList() it.

Comment: @Will: silly question: how would I capture the line that immediately following the error line?

Comment: @inquisitive_one: You're getting beyond the scope of Linq.

Comment: @Will:  Yes, Tim pointed that out to me.  I thought it would be something easy for LINQ.  Now, I'm trying his way.

Comment: This CAN be done with LINQ, but it will not be pretty/elegant/MAINTAINABLE. LINQ should really only be used when it's a clearer representation of WHAT you want to do, and not about HOW you want to do it. Unfortunately, using LINQ, it will be worse in terms of readability, even worse in terms of maintainability (coming back to it months later, you will have a WTF moment), and it will not be very efficient (multiple enumerations GUARANTEED).

Comment: @inquisitive_one: Yuck took care of it this time, but in general you should respond to requests for clarifications by updating your post, rather than replying with a comment. For one thing, a question should be understandable without reading comments. For another, SO is a QA & site, not a forum, and comments aren't intended (nor are they well suited) for discussions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LINQ is not the right tool if you want to modify what you're iterating. It's also not appropriate if you need to use an indexer largely.

This is another approach that should help you:

```
var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Temp\Data.csv");
var result = new List<String>();
var errors = new List<Tuple<int, String, String>>();
for (int i = 0; i < data.Length; i++)
{
    var line = data[i];
    var cols = line.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    if (cols[0].ToUpper() == "ERROR")
    {
        var nextLine = data.Length > i+1 ? data[i + 1].Replace("\"\"","") : String.Empty;
        var nextCols = nextLine.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Where(col => !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(col) && !(col.Trim() == "0"));
        var errorInfo = Tuple.Create(i, line, String.Join(",", nextCols));
        errors.Add(errorInfo);
        i++;
    }
    else {
        result.Add(line);
    }
}
foreach(var error in errors)
{
    result.Add(error.Item2);
    result.Add(error.Item3);
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is does not all what you need since it doesn't modify the error-line(it's not entirely  clear how), but maybe you're now on the right track :)

Comment: is there an easy way to figure that out?  But you've definitely pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: @inquisitive_one: Then define clearly what should be removed and why. I see the `""` but is this only an example? In your sample data there's also one field more than in the other lines, but is this always the case(perhaps sometimes even more illegal fields with different content)?

Comment: Yes, that was an example.  95% of the time that field will always be null.  There is an odd time that it would be 0.  And yes, the following line after the ERROR will always have 1 extra field.

Comment: @inquisitive_one: Edited my answer to match your requirement. It handles now also `""`, `null`, empty strings/white spaces and `"0"` by simply removing that field.

Comment: Thx @Tim.  But how would I retain the data as a list rather than a string?

Comment: @inquisitive_one: I don't understand, the variable `result` is a `List<String>`.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Tim.  Right now, if I take the 1st element of the list.  ex:  result[0].ToString() //Ans:  I get the 1st letter of each line.  Is it possible to use an array instead?  (Sorry for the newbie question.  I'm still trying to get a handle on C# & Linq.)

Comment: @inquisitive_one: I'm not sure if you're using another code that mine. I'm creating a `List<String>` where every item is one line as string. So this is the first line(and you don't need to call `ToString()` on it): `var firstLine=result[0];`. If you want the first letter you need `firstLine[0];`. If you don't want the list(whyever), you could simply call `var resultArray=result.ToArray()` at the end of my code.

Answer (score 0):

Other warnings notwithstanding, providing a LINQ solution is worth considering even if it ultimately isn't the right solution for this problem.

I'll offer a LINQ solution, with the caveats that a proper production-worthy solution should do error checking and argument validation including checks that the file is properly formed that are interesting but beyond the scope of what is requested here and often a bit of a challenge to do completely functionally.

```
var myList = 
    File.ReadLines(myFile.ToString(), Encoding.GetEncoding(1250))
    .Select(line => 
    {
        var split = line.Split(',');
        return new specialclass
        {
            Comp = split[0],
            Place = Convert.ToInt32(split[1]),
            Name = split[2],
            Limit = Convert.ToInt32(split[3]),
            Limit2 = Convert.ToInt32(split[4])
        };
    })
    .ToList();

var itemsAndPrevious = new specialclass [] { null }
    .Concat(myList)
    .Zip(myList, (prev,item) => new { prev, item });

var itemsWithoutError =
    itemsAndPrevious
        .Where(i => i.item.Comp != "Error" // omit error line
            && (i.prev == null || i.prev.Comp != "Error")) // omit line following error lines
        .Select(i => i.item)
        .OrderBy(i => i.Comp);

var itemsWithError = 
    itemsAndPrevious.Where(i => i.prev != null && i.prev.Comp == "Error")
    .OrderBy(i => i.item.Comp)
    .SelectMany(i => new [] { i.prev, i.item });

var desiredResult = itemsWithoutError.Concat(itemsWithError);
```

If you plan on running this only on data with anywhere from a few hundred or even a few thousand entries, this may perform well enough that you won't need to find more efficient solutions. What is important is that you don't assume that any implementation will be fast enough - time them, just to be sure. You should also see how doubling the input size affects the run time of the code - then you can form predictions on how well this will perform on larger and larger input sizes.

I offer no warranty that the above code is either tested or bug-free.
`Zip` was added in 4.0 so it won't be available if you are using a framework prior to that. Otherwise, implementing your own `Zip` is a worthwhile exercise. Happy coding.